# I cannot delete s3 object using one method, but i can delete using another. (obj.delete vs delete_object)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

What is the difference between deleting s3 objects using client session delete_object method and obj.delete method?

While calling

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key_emr,
                        region_name=region_name)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key='input/df.parquet')
```

the code run without any error.

But the following code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, "input/df.parquet")
obj.delete()
```

lead to the ClientError; An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied

The similar thing happens while using aws data wrangler library. The running of following code

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.delete_objects(f"s3://{bucket_name}/input/df.parquet")
```

doesn't delete anything, and doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's solved, i have defined s3 as a `boto3.resource('s3')` instead of `session.resource('s3')`